# How to properly reduce the size of a tensorflow savedmodel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a tensorflow pre-trained model in a checkpoint form, and I intended to deploy the model for serving by converting the model into the `savedmodel` form. The size of the saved model is kind of too large. (The "variables.data-00000-of-0001" file in the savedmodel is more than hundred of MBs.) I googled how to reduce the size of variables, but I could not find a good answer. Could you help me understand how to reduce the size of variables in a tensorflow savedmodel? It will be great to show a simple example. Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971050/graph-optimizations-on-a-tensorflow-serveable-created-using-tf-estimator