# Graph optimizations on a tensorflow serveable created using tf.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

**Context**:

I have a simple classifier based on [tf.estimator.DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) that takes text and output probabilities over an intent tags.  I am able to train an export the model to a serveable as well as serve the serveable using [tensorflow serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup).  The problem is this servable is too big (around 1GB) and so I wanted to try some [tensorflow graph transforms](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#shrinking-file-size) to try to reduce the size of the files being served.

**Problem**:

I understand how to take the `saved_model.pb` and use [freeze_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) to create a new `.pb` file that can be used to call transforms on. The result of these transforms (a `.pb` file as well) is not a servable and cannot be used with tensorflow serving.

How can a developer go from:

```
saved model -> graph transforms -> back to a servable
```

There's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models) that suggests that this is certainly possible, but its not at all intuitive from the docs as to how to do this.

**What I've Tried**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.saved_model import simple_save
from tensorflow.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.saved_model import tag_constants
from tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms import TransformGraph


with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess_meta:
    meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess_meta,
        [tag_constants.SERVING],
        "/model/path")

    graph_def = meta_graph_def.graph_def

    other_graph_def = TransformGraph(
        graph_def,
        ["Placeholder"],
        ["dnn/head/predictions/probabilities"],
        ["quantize_weights"])


    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        tf.import_graph_def(other_graph_def)
        in_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            "import/Placeholder:0")
        out_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(
            "import/dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0")

        inputs = {"inputs": in_tensor}
        outputs = {"outputs": out_tensor}

        simple_save(sess_meta, "./new", inputs, outputs)
```

My idea was to load the servable, extract the graph_def from the meta_graph_def, transform the graph_def and then try to recreate the servable.  This seems to be the incorrect approach.

Is there a way to successfully perform transforms (to reduce file size at inference) on a graph from an exported servable, and then recreate a servable with the transformed graph?

Thanks.

**Update (2018-08-28)**:

Found [contrib.meta_graph_transform()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/contrib/meta_graph_transform/meta_graph_transform.py) which looks promising.

**Update (2018-12-03)**:

A related [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1078#issuecomment-443906077) I opened that seems to be resolved in a detailed blog post which is listed at the end of the ticket.

Comment: I've actually done something similar before. I always convert to saved_model instead of frozen model, then I wanted to try some optimization.

After hours of searching, I made a script that converts a saved_model2frozen_model and frozen_model2saved_model.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go from a SavedModel to a servable after running tensorflow graph transforms is to use the SavedModel Builder API.

First, you need to create a SavedModel Builder object and then rebuild the graph you have just transformed, using the SavedModel Builder API.

Next, you need to add the assets, signatures, and other meta-data back into the model. Finally, you need to call the SavedModel Builder API's save() method, which will save the model as a servable.

This servable can then be used with tensorflow serving.